# How to right-click or move mouse to a element used selenium with python?

Tags: python

For Example: Get icon of [google](https://www.google.com/)

```
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME,'body'))
    )
    gmail = driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, 'Gmail')
    google_icon = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "lnXdpd")
    action  = ActionChains(driver)
    
    action.context_click(google_icon)

finally:
    pass
```

the `context_click` don't work.so I try

```
    # test second
    action.move_to_element(google_icon)
    # action.context_click(on_element=None)
    action.context_click(google_icon)
```

It's don't work too. but

```
gmail.click()
```

this is can work.what should i do.

Comment: Have you checked if `action.context_click(on_element=google_icon)` works?

Comment: What, exactly, are you trying to do by right-clicking on the icon?